# BencodeNET reading from list c#

Tags: c#

Hey I have been using bencodeNET for a while and it works great with one file torrents but when it comes to multiple file torrents it stores the filenames in a list, this shouldn't be a problem but it seems to be.

dosent matter how I try to read from the list I always end up with a error

```
string search = "5";
string result = torrent.Files.Single(se => se == search);
```

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TorrentFile.TorrentFileFileEntry' and 'string'

https://github.com/Krusen/BencodeNET/blob/master/BencodeNET/Torrents/TorrentMultiFileInfo.cs

I do feel that the answer is here but cant figure it out how it should be implemented, thanks for any help

Comment: something like `torrent.Files.Single(se => se.FileName.StartsWith(search));` ?? The error is explanitory, you have a string and you are comparing it to some type that is not a string (a TorrentFileEntry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`se` is an object of type `TorrentFileFileEntry`, which you are trying to compare to a `string` - this won't work as they are objects of different types.

Perhaps you should be searching a property of `se`, e.g. `se => se.FileName == search`.

*I'm guessing the property name here.*

Comment: I understand your way but I cant guess out the property name or get it from the source

Comment: @BoKKeR, can you check the API documentation or use IntelliSense?

Comment: api documentation is 0, just what you see on github. IntelliSense tells me only http://puu.sh/qVa9q/c2da13c349.png could it be that its just not implemented ?

Comment: @BoKKeR, I think what you see there is all that is available, perhaps trying debugging and then inspecting the `Path` and `FileSize` properties manually. They might contain the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and help :) have a nice day